# Apache Proxy Load Balancing and Taking App Servers Out of Rotation

Tags: proxy, apache-2.4

We have four Apache servers acting as proxy servers to 8 application servers (for the sake of argument Tomcat servers).  We use Apache to proxy/forward the requests to the application servers.  The application servers are added as "balance members" on the Apache servers.  My question is...if one of the application servers goes down, is the only way to take that application server out of rotation to remove the node from the "balance member" list on the Apache servers?   Is there an easier way than manually editing the httpd.conf file?  Is there a way to to remove the application server node from the Apache proxy list?

Answer (score 0):

From the term "Balance members" i can guess you're using mod_proxy with mod_proxy_http or mod_proxy_ajp.

If it's so, you can manage to just get down any of your "tomcat's" without other intervention and when apache finds that particular instance, if it's configured so, it'll push the request to another "tomcat" instance without the user noticing it.

This assuming that that particular tomcat's instance port is closed (RST packet).

You can use a web interface too, to take on / off balanced members, check this:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#balancer_manager